# what to do if the tkinter is not working in python ? mainloop is nor working at all

Tags: python, tkinter

OK if i type this code in visual studio code :

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.mainloop
```

it is not working , without even a error. it shows:

```
PS C:\Users\lenovo> & C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe c:/Users/lenovo/OneDrive/Desktop/mayank/tkinter/prjt1.py
PS C:\Users\lenovo>
```

this is not working at all

Answer (score 2):

You forgot about () in root.mainloop

Right code:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.mainloop()
```